# Browser launch fails for second time through remote webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, remotewebdriver

I'm running several tests via selenium remote webdriver on remote machine. For each test i will be rebooting the VM and then restart the browser. For the first case browser launch is successful but on other iterations browser launch fails. **However if i start another selenium server with different port, then second test gets executed with the new port.**

Not sure why the first port couldn't be reused for the second time ?

Error is showing as below:-

> ERROR in invoking Selenium Commands:Could not start a new session.
>   Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser
>   start-up failure.
>
> > System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch:
> >     'i386', java.version:
> >      '1.8.0_31'

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "40.0.2");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "WINDOWS");
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "firefox");
driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://"+ipaddress+":"+portNumber+"/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Selenium server launched in VM as java -jar selenium-server.2.42.2.jar

Comment: hi, once VM is restarted, did you started node in that VM?

Comment: yes. selenium server will be started automatically. please note I'm not running node/hub with this setup. using remote webdriver and running scripts using VM ip